# Convert screen coordinates to picture coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, windows-mobile, coordinates

I have the following problem: A program displays a picture using a `PictureBox`. The picture contains two rectangles A and B that are drawn after the image is loaded.

[image: Illustration]

The image inside the picture box is zoomed and the rectangles A and B are painted using the `Graphics` object of the loaded image. Is there a simple method to determinate if a user clicked the area inside these rectangles e.g. converting screen coordinates to picture coordinates.

*Edit: No longer relevant, found another solution.*

*Edit 2: My solution was to use two picture boxes at the A and B location instead of modifying the image directly. It has some minor disadvantages specific to my solution, but I had to finish the project in time*

Comment: You should consider writing a few lines about the solution you found. Otherwise, this thread might turn up in a search later and annoy someone with the same problem quite badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419933/pictureboxsizemode-zoom-whats-the-zoom-factor) discusses the zoom factor of a picture box and that you cannot determine it.

Therefore I think, without getting the zoom factor, you may not be able to calculate the position.